# Apps Script not running for Drive extraction

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-apps-script-editor

I am quite new to the platform.

I tried to make a Google Apps Script to fetch me the file details from my Google folder. I found the script from Stack Overflow again.

It was working all good until there seem to be an error in running now. I am not able to diagnose the same.

I have now created a copy of the exact same file.

In the file there is a sheet named "Script Logs" where the data's were logged.

The script is named 'Drive files'. In which the function 'listAll' is to be run.

When run I get to check the loggers and find "Exception: Bad value"

The details from the file to be extracted is a little confidential and that is why I have not shared.

[Bug screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9dPo.png)

Please help me in correcting the code. The file is in this link.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ktUe3qyf-TJp4K_FC8ELzLgh5q7jNRCP8YJF-z2li4A/edit?usp=sharing
Below is the code used for it.

```
/** 
* Google Apps Script - List all files & folders in a Google Drive folder, 
& write into a speadsheet.
*    - Main function 1: List all folders
*    - Main function 2: List all files & folders
* 
* Hint: Set your folder ID first! You may copy the folder ID from the 
browser's address field. 
*       The folder ID is everything after the 'folders/' portion of the 
URL.
* 
* @version 1.0
* @see     https://github.com/mesgarpour
*/

// TODO: Set folder ID
var folderId = '0B_BwvZZtlhP4OFNTeUhLX2NCWk0';

// Main function 1: List all folders, & write into the current sheet.
function listFolers(){
getFolderTree(folderId, false);
};

// Main function 2: List all files & folders, & write into the current 
sheet.
function listAll(){
getFolderTree(folderId, true); 
};

// =================
// Get Folder Tree
function getFolderTree(folderId, listAll) {
try {
// Get folder by id
var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);

// Initialise the sheet
var file, data, sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("d/1qP7AoydxJs7IkiURkLKkOzUSxTd1Ha8jLmETBq54zgI").getSheetByName("Script Logs")
sheet.clear();
sheet.appendRow(["Full Path", "Name", "Date", "URL", "Last Updated", 
"Description", "Size"]);

// Get files and folders
getChildFolders(parentFolder.getName(), parentFolder, data, sheet, 
listAll);

} catch (e) {
Logger.log(e.toString());
}
};

// Get the list of files and folders and their metadata in recursive mode
function getChildFolders(parentName, parent, data, sheet, listAll) {
var childFolders = parent.getFolders();

// List folders inside the folder
while (childFolders.hasNext()) {
var childFolder = childFolders.next();
// Logger.log("Folder Name: " + childFolder.getName());

data = [ 
  parentName + "/" + childFolder.getName(),
  childFolder.getName(),
  childFolder.getDateCreated(),
  childFolder.getUrl(),
  childFolder.getLastUpdated(),
  childFolder.getDescription(),
  childFolder.getSize() / 1024,
];
// Write
sheet.appendRow(data);

// List files inside the folder
var files = childFolder.getFiles();
while (listAll & files.hasNext()) {
  var childFile = files.next();
  // Logger.log("File Name: " + childFile.getName());
  data = [ 
    parentName + "/" + childFolder.getName() + "/" + childFile.getName(),
    childFile.getName(),
    childFile.getDateCreated(),
    childFile.getUrl(),
    childFile.getLastUpdated(),
    childFile.getDescription(),
    childFile.getSize() / 1024, 

  ];
  // Write
  sheet.appendRow(data);
}

// Recursive call of the subfolder
getChildFolders(parentName + "/" + childFolder.getName(), childFolder, 
data, sheet, listAll);  
} 
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to replace `'My folder ID'` with the actual folder ID. Checkout this https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Ruben. But I have now updated the code and it was already given. The code was running properly before.Now the logs says Bad value.

Comment: Posts on this site should not include greetings, salutations, and other no required content to describe the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/behaviour. Regarding the error, add the textual error message to the question.

Comment: It is already given in the question.

Comment: Usually the error message include the line number where the error occurred and sometimes also include the related variable or method. The question doesn't include these details.

Comment: added bug screenshot.

Comment: The screenshot doesn't show the textual error message.

Comment: This is all I can see... If you can specify where to find what you are talking about, it will be easier

Comment: Where do you saw"Exception: Bad value" ?

Comment: I found it in Logs

Comment: You can help me out ? @Ruben

Comment: @VimalT The debug snapshot doesn't give "where and why" the code failed. Line 38 is suspect: `openById("d/1qP7AoydxJs7IkiURkLKkOzUSxTd1Ha8jLmETBq54zgI")`. Refer the documentation of syntax for [`openById`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid); the leading "d/" should not be included. Would you please run your function, then immediately view the Execution Transcript ( Script Editor> View> Execution Transcript). This will show the exact line and error message; copy the **entire** Transcript and post it back here in your question.